# How to boot up Surface 3 in English

Tags: windows-10-preview, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I just got my Surface and as I boot it up, I see some languages but those are all Scandinavian (Swedish, Norwegian, Danish, Finnish). I can select the app language to English but the rest stays in Swedish.

How can I reset and reboot the device so it's all in English?

Can it be done if I install Windows 10 (preview)?

Comment: You would have the same problem since you would have to use the same language version of Windows 10 so that isn't really a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the language in windows 8 by:

1. Swiping in from the right and clicking on "Settings".
2. Click on "Change PC Settings"
3. Click "Time and language"
4. Click on "Region and language"
5. Click on the language you want and click "Set As Primary"
6. Log out and log in

Reference from [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/using-multiple-languages) where they also talk about how to install alternate languages.

This should be identical in result to the old way it was done in windows 7 but I'll include a [reference](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-system-locale#1TC=windows-7) to it as well.  This would be accomplished in Desktop mode (Control Panel -> Language and Region -> Administrative -> Change System Locale.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced you're right. I've set English as primary language but I can still see some Swedish in tiles, for instance. Also, the whole installation procedure, sync with the pend etc. was done in Swedish. I want to go all-English (except for the input language and Swedish keyboard). I.e. I wish **the core** to be English and put some Swedish on top, not the other way around. Is that doable?

Comment: Once you get your language set the way you want it, you could refresh the system to force windows to reinstall those tiles.  If you don't want the nuclear option, you can check [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/178667/how-to-reset-the-windows-8.x-start-screen-to-the-default-tiles/) and reset the tiles to default which should trigger English and not Swedish.